# where to find the norm-conserving pseudopotential of rare earth metals?

Tags: density-functional-theory, pseudopotentials

I am trying to find the norm-conserving(NC) pseudopotential of rare earth metals, but all I could find are about Ultrasoft or PAW types. Is there any recommendation for NC type?

Comment: Do you want to make your own, or are you looking for existing ones? It's quite difficult to make good norm-conserving potentials for f-block elements, without requiring an extremely large cut-off energy. You would definitely want multiple-projector (per channel) norm-conserving potentials, if your software supports it.

Comment: @PhilHasnip. Looking for existing ones. I am also considering using Multi-projector ONCVPSP-4.0.1 to generate custom potentials.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?

Comment: I tried to use data from this paper https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00553